# How do I use the Membership methods in the database layer?

Tags: membership

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 3-tiered app. I want ALL of the db interaction to go through the db layer. So, when I use the Login controls, instead of them calling methods that hit the db, I want them to call down the layers until I reach the db layer. At that point I would call the Membership methods to, say, login, check the username,etc. However, I can't seem to reference the membership class in the class project that is my db layer. I tried setting a reference to System.Web.Security but it's not in my list, even though I can use these methods in the ui layer. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Web.Security is in the System.Web assembly.